# 403 Forbidden on Django Storages css/js files with Amazon S3 on an EC2 Instance

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have been googling for two days and none of the answers are resolving the issue.

**The setup**

```
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxx'
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket.mycompany.com'
COMPRESS_URL = 'http://{}.s3.amazon.com/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
STATIC_URL = COMPRESS_URL
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '{}.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

**The googling**

[Incorrect date/time on server](http://abourazanis.com/2014/Amazon-S3-403-forbidden-Error/)  :  This an EC-2 instance, but even though I installed `yum install ntp ntpdate ntp-doc` -- NO LUCK

[AWS_QUERY_STRING_AUTH](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/229) : Multiple sources online say to do this, but didn't resolve my issue

[AWS_QUERY_STRING_AUTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651052/why-are-my-compressed-files-on-s3-returning-a-403-forbidden-error): Yet again

[AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623901/error-when-trying-to-compress-static-files-when-using-django-storages-and-django) No luck here either

**The experiment**

```
# ON THE EC2 BOX
./manage.py shell
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from django.conf import settings
conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
b = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket.mycompany.com')
key = b.get_key('500.html')
print key.get_contents_as_string()  # WORKS FINE
```

However when I run `./manage.py compress` I get

```
CommandError: An error occured during renderinghome_4770.html:
'https://mybucket.mycompany.com.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css'
 isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL    ('http://mybucket.mycompany.com.s3.amazon.com/') and can't be compressed
```

Before you ask, yes the file is available on that bucket.  I also tried the traditional way of django-storages with offline compression, using `<project-root>/static` as `STATIC_ROOT`, then uploading the contents of `./manage.py collectstatic` AND `./manage.py compress` :, i.e. the resulting css/js and `manifest_1.json` files to the bucket, but in the browser, I still get `403 Forbidden` on css/js files

Any ideas on what may be going on??

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a CORS policy on your bucket? You might also need to add a permission to allow "Everyone" to "List" objects in the bucket (although try the CORS policy first)

Edit: 
Here are the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: I tried both and neither seems to work.  The error remains the same.  My CORS policy is both GET and PUT

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your css file metadata ( ==> File ==> Properties)?

make sure they are set as css files and not as:
"binary/octet-stream"

Like AWS does sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that seems to be caused by mixing `storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage` with `storage.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`.

I didn't have time to diagnose the problem (which probably involved my `CACHES` setup), but not using `storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage` with S3 fixed my issue.

I am using the [django-require-s3](https://github.com/etianen/django-require-s3/) package and had the following settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'require_s3.storage.OptimizedCachedStaticFilesStorage'
```

First solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110977/1074659

```
# Add
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Second solution:

```
# Alter
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'require_s3.storage.OptimizedStaticFilesStorage'
```